# How to kill two processes launching each other

Tags: linux, process

Let's suppose I have a pool of processes which watches each other and if one or more are killed, the other re-spawn them.

How can I kill something like this? Or if this question is too broad, can someone at least point me to different approaches to this?

I know this is pretty wide question, but hopefully someone will know the answer.

I'm mainly interested in Linux, but info regarding Windows could be useful too.

Comment: sounds like you need to make sure your script is needed to be a critical priority, so the other threads dont run to respawn killed threads

Comment: The answer to this is not easy when you consider race conditions.

Comment: I think it would be best to not have cycles in your restart dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a single `kill` command with the pids of all the processes in the pool, listed?

```
kill 23 34 56 666 789 543
```

Also, try the same with -9 option, to send  a SIGKILL.

```
kill -9 23 34 56 666 789 543
```